# Displaying command button with image only

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to display a button with image only on my page but all I see is the button with ^. Following is the code for my button:

```
<p:commandButton onclick="lineSearch.show();" image="backgroung-image:url(/images/title_logo.jpg)"/> 
<p:dialog header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="lineSearch" modal="true" onCloseUpdate="lineIdField" showEffect="scale" hideEffect="explode">  
    <ui:include src="lineSearch.xhtml"/>
</p:dialog>
```

The image does exist in the images folder. The button is rendered as following in the page:

```
<button id="j_idt23:j_idt27" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" type="submit" onclick="lineSearch.show();;PrimeFaces.ab({formId:'j_idt23',source:'j_idt23:j_idt27',process:'@all'});return false;" name="j_idt23:j_idt27" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon backgroung-image:url(/images/title_logo.jpg)"></span>
    <span class="ui-button-text">ui-button</span>
</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    widget_j_idt23_j_idt27 = new PrimeFaces.widget.CommandButton('j_idt23:j_idt27', {text:false,icons:{primary:'backgroung-image:url(/images/title_logo.jpg)'}});
</script>
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Did it really render `backgroung-image`?

Comment: @BalusC this is what it rendered: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0d9nm5ueb

Comment: Why did you edit the question to copy this incorrect style property in the `image` attribute?

Comment: What code do you **really** have (in XHTML file) and what did it **really** render? (in the HTML source)? Please do not edit the copypaste, you'll possibly remove the error without actually realizing it or even introduce new errors (like with your last edit).

Comment: @BalusC I am sorry for editing the code. This is actually what's there right now and what's rendered.

Comment: @BalusC I was trying out different things and had two tabs open for the same page. So I copied the rendered html from the older version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My own primefaces p:commanButton icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619707/my-own-primefaces-pcommanbutton-icon)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The `image` attribute has to refer a CSS **class name**, not a plain CSS property. So, this should do:

```html
<p:commandButton image="someCssClassName" />
```

with the following in your CSS:

```
.someCssClassName {
    background-image: url(images/title_logo.jpg)
}
```

Please note that I fixed the major typo in property name and also removed the leading slash from the image URL, it would otherwise be resolved relative to the site's domain root; the above expects the `title_logo.jpg` to be inside an `/image` folder which in turn is in the folder where the CSS file resides.

However, this one is less clumsy, I think:

```html
<p:commandLink action="#{bean.submit}">
    <h:graphicImage name="images/title_logo.jpg" />
</p:commandLink>
```

Comment: @Olivier: please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used for a related question on how to use JSF resources (this is what the `name` attribute is pointing to).

Comment: hum ok. In my case the `name` attribute did not work because I didn't create library associated to. Sorry for this bad edit BalusC

Comment: @Olivier: Apparently you didn't put it in `/resources` folder. The particular example in my answer expects the image file to be in `/resources/images/title_logo.jpg`.

Comment: Note that the `image` attribute has now been deprecated, use `icon` attribute instead.

Comment: Migrating from richfaces.. the only one to work its the commanLink, without adding more css.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use "P:coomandLink" and "P:graphicImage" at the same time.
I have created a folder under webapps, and put my jpg file under this folder.
This code works fine for me.
good luck.

```
<p:commandLink action="#{MyClass.myMethod}">
   <p:graphicImage value="images/Max-Burger.jpg"  />
</p:commandLink>
```

Comment: the only solution that worked for me with Primefaces 12.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put this on your css style:

```
    .dolar-icon {
    background-image: url("#{facesContext.externalContext.request.contextPath}/resources/imagenes/dolar.png") !important;}
```

Now you can use the icon "dolar-icon" that you defined in your css.

```
<p:commandButton action="#{as.fe}" icon="dolar-icon"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Even easier:

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-XXXXX">
```

Diferent icons you can choose: https://api.jqueryui.com/theming/icons/ and http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/fa.xhtml

Comment: That is only easier if you want an existing icon. If you want your own image (like the OP did) this does not work at all.

Comment: Just an easy way to do it