# Display a background Image for a commandbutton

Tags: css, primefaces

I am using primefaces as a library and I'm trying to display an image in the background of a commanbutton.
Here is my code:

```
  <p:commandButton image="button_image" type="submit" ajax="false" action="#{loginMB.connect()}"></p:commandButton>
```

In my style sheet i added this structure:

```
.button_image {
    background-image: url(../images/login.png) !important;
    width:82px;
    height:32px;
    border:0px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 24px;
}
```

But what i get as a result is this 
[image]

And I am looking for this [image]

Comment: Did you try so use `icon` instead of `image`? Because `image` is deprecated as stated in the Primeface documentation.

Comment: Did you read [Displaying command button with image only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003440/displaying-command-button-with-image-only) and [My own primefaces p:commanButton icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619707/my-own-primefaces-pcommanbutton-icon) ?